# Rails 3.1 app in subdirectory, asset paths not generating correctly in my sass file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a rails 3.1 app deployed in a subdirectory (/customers) on Apache+Passenger, using this method http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

In /app/assets/stylesheets/app.css.erb this code

```
background: url(<%=image_path("top.jpg")%>)
```

generates

```
background: url(/assets/top.jpg)
```

instead of /customers/assets/top.jpg

In my views,

```
image_path("top.jpg")
```

will generate

```
/customers/assets/top.jpg
```

like I expect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use asset_path inside your CSS instead of image_path.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, just changed my code to that and it still generates the same, incorrect css.

Comment: Are you on 3.1.0 or 3.1.1? I recall seeing a fix for a relative path issue in Rails, but not sure what version.

Answer (score 0):

background: image-url("top.jpg")

should work after renaming to .css.scss